# How can I configure a home proxy server only with router?

Tags: hardware, proxy, router, transparent-proxy

I want to connect: [work] <-> [proxyWork] <-> [myHome] <-> [www]

I want to configure myHome as a proxy server but I don't want to switch on my home computer for all days. Does it exists any (possibly cheap) hardware that can act as a router with proxy capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [pfsense](http://pfsense.org/). It has a proxy package post install, it is officially designed for embedded systems (such as home routers). You'll have to look into their compatibility to make sure whatever you have is up to date.

On a side note, make sure that you secure the proxy server as these are very very tasty treats for any malicious individuals on the web. Just because your not a 'big' target doesn't make you any safer if your going to run one of these.

Comment: "officially designed for embedded systems (such as home routers)". What do you mean? I'm reading that I have to install pfsense in my pc and it seems it's not possible to include in my own router (a d-link)

Comment: Although pfSense would be ideal in this scenario, I am not aware of anyone getting it working on a dlink residential router. The embedded version runs on various AMD Geode based systems and some older hardware firewalls (nokias for example) that people may have lying around. However, I did setup one of these boxes before on a mini-ITX system (Intel ATOM) for about 250 GBP all in - however any old Pentium PC will do. It depends how much you want that proxy.

Comment: Personally I have it running on an old junker thought you could flash some commercial routers with it. Looking again it might not be the best option if that's the route you'd like to go. There are other options for flashing to a 'smarter' router using firmware such as ddwrt or openwrt, there is some risk to the router involved so make sure you read the installation and compatibility information on the respective websites